# How do I get my current build commit's sha1 in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, git, android-studio

How can I access the current build commit's sha1 of my project from Java code?

This is preferred but not obligatory:

1. Getting the shortened version of sha1 (say, 6 first chars)
2. A solution without any side libraries or frameworks

I'm using OS.X v. 10.10,  Android Studio v. 1.2.2.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this information in gradle. For example you can use this function

```
def gitHash() {
    try {
        def process = 'git log -1 --format=%H'.execute()
        def longHash = process.getText().trim()
        println 'gitHash is ' + longHash
        longHash
    }
    catch (ignore) {
        println 'unable to get git hash'
        'ERROR'
    }
}
```

and you can assign the value to (for example) your client version. Then you can retrieve the client version from your app. You need git on your PATH, and you can change the format (--format) to get the desired one.